# Doing a one step Cox PH regression for 4 time intervals in R

Tags: r, statistics, survival-analysis

I have 4 intervals of interest:

- 0 - 30 days
- 30 days - ½ year
- ½ - 2 years
- 2 years - 10 years

Right now I'm subsetting my dataset like this:

```
# Set time period
time_period.first <-  30/365.25
time_period.intermediate <- .5
....

# TREOP = Time in years
data.first = all_data
# Remove already censored data
data.intermediate = subset(data.first, data.first$TREOP > time_period.first)

# Set all outside as censored
data.first$RREOP[data.first$TREOP > time_period.first] = 0
data.first$TREOP[data.first$TREOP > time_period.first] = time_period.first

data.intermediate$RREOP[data.intermediate$TREOP > time_period.second] = 0
data.intermediate$TREOP[data.intermediate$TREOP > time_period.second] = time_period.second
....
```

I'm doing cox regression with the 'survival' package (I also use the cph in the 'Design' package for C-statistic calculations).

#### My question:

Is there a better way of performing this left-truncation & right-censoring?

Ideal would be:

```
# TREOP - time in years
# RREOP - event
surv <- Surv(TREOP, RREOP, start=30/365.25, stop=.5)
```

I've looked at the help and the time, time2 & type seem to do handle truncation but I think that it's for a more complex setting where subjects enter the study after 22 days and not for splitting data into intervals.

#### Edit

I've found the survSplit() function in the survival package but although it by description seems right I'm not sure how to tame it - the example doesn't really help me out. Anyone have any experience with it?

Answer (score 0):

1. I agree with right-censoring which looks simple and straightforward.
2. I'm not sure that you should left-truncate. I would feel more comfortable leaving the shorter survival times unchanged and just increase the upper censoring limit. If the n'th time period is much longer than the (n-1)'th - it won't matter much and if it is not much longer than the shorter survival times shouldn't be truncated.

Comment: The intervals are somewhat for historical reasons. What I'm looking for is an easy way failsafe way of defining the time-periods. The method that I'm using works and left truncating the same way has been done in previous studies. I'm interested in a more "elegant" solution than mine where I have multiple datasets introducing possible errors...

Comment: Well, if you only right censor than it would be straightforward to have a loop over an array of right-censor times and within this loop censor and perform the Cox analysis for the current censor

Comment: Thanks but I was wondering if there is a function already built-in to the survival functions since this seems like a very frequent thing to do. I should be able to separate different time periods just by specifying the time-strata...